# More efficient way to enable/disable multiple input fields JS

Tags: javascript, html

PROBLEM:

I have form which submits list of fields. My form includes 2 'overwrite' fields:

counter - how many items to be submitted
field overwrite - if filled it suppose to overwrite all inputs  in table with the same value

finally I have 5 field inputs (field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4 and field_5).

What I am trying to do is:

Counter - when filled it will disable field_ with number lower than value in counter, eg. when counter = 3, inputs field_4 and field_5 will get disabled.

field_0 - when empty, I would like user to be able to fill anything in table. When populated, I would like field_0 to be copied over to all cells in table.

WHAT I HAVE DONE:

I currently have extremely inefficient working code. I have complicated 'if' statement which checks counter and field_0 individually for every single of items (field_1 - field_5) one by one and sets them to enable/disable or copies over field_0 value. I also have 'clearFieldClass' function which clears all items with class 'field' when field_0 is being changed. While it works for 5 fields and one field type final version of the page will have 200 fields x 10 different classes. I am trying to avoid having 2000 lines of code doing basically he same thing.

```js
function clearFieldClass() {
        var elements = [] ;
       elements = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
       for(var i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){
       elements[i].value = "" ;
       }
      }
```

```html
    <form action="https://www.tobesubmitted.to.com?" onchange="    
     if (counter.value > 0 && field_0.value == '') {document.getElementById('field_1').disabled = false;} else if (counter.value > 0 && field_0.value !== '') {field_1.value = field_0.value, document.getElementById('field_1').disabled = false;} else {document.getElementById('field_1').disabled = true; field_1.value = ''};    
     if (counter.value > 1 && field_0.value == '') {document.getElementById('field_2').disabled = false;} else if (counter.value > 1 && field_0.value !== '') {field_2.value = field_0.value, document.getElementById('field_2').disabled = false;} else {document.getElementById('field_2').disabled = true; field_2.value = ''};    
     if (counter.value > 2 && field_0.value == '') {document.getElementById('field_3').disabled = false;} else if (counter.value > 2 && field_0.value !== '') {field_3.value = field_0.value, document.getElementById('field_3').disabled = false;} else {document.getElementById('field_3').disabled = true; field_3.value = ''};    
     if (counter.value > 3 && field_0.value == '') {document.getElementById('field_4').disabled = false;} else if (counter.value > 3 && field_0.value !== '') {field_4.value = field_0.value, document.getElementById('field_4').disabled = false;} else {document.getElementById('field_4').disabled = true; field_4.value = ''};    
     if (counter.value > 4 && field_0.value == '') {document.getElementById('field_5').disabled = false;} else if (counter.value > 4 && field_0.value !== '') {field_5.value = field_0.value, document.getElementById('field_5').disabled = false;} else {document.getElementById('field_5').disabled = true; field_5.value = ''};  
    ">       
    <table border="0">
     <tr>
      <th align="left">Overwrites</th>
         <th></th>         
       </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label>Counter </label></td>
      <td><input required type="text" id="counter" name="counter" placeholder="Max 50"></input></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label>Overwrite field: </label></td>
      <td><input required type="text" id="field_0" name="field_0" placeholder="Field" onchange="clearFieldClass()"></input></td>
     </tr>     
    </table><br><br>    
    <table>
     <tr align="left">
         <th>Field</th> 
     </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><input required type="text" class='field' id="field_1"></td> 
     </tr>       
       <tr>
         <td><input required type="text" class='field' id="field_2"></td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input required type="text" class='field' id="field_3"></td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input required type="text" class='field' id="field_4"></td> 
     </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><input required type="text" class='field' id="field_5"></td> 
     </tr>   
    </table>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form"></input>
```

Comment: Why don't you just try to write `disabled` at the end of each inputs that you want to disable and then write your js code to enable it on your specified condition?

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is to stop using tables for layout. The second thing you can do is use a `fieldset` element to wrap the fields, and disable the `fieldset`. This won't work in IE though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove onchange attribute from your html and use the following code:

```
 document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change', () => {
   document.querySelectorAll('.field').forEach((_el, index) => {

 if(!isNaN(+counter.value) && +counter.value != 0  && index + 1 > +counter.value){
  _el.disabled = 'disabled';
  _el.value = '';
  console.log('in')
 }

 else{
  _el.removeAttribute('disabled');
  _el.value = field_0.value;
 }
   });
 })
```

Comment: This is excellent! Exactly what I needed. I added _el.value = ''; to not only disable fields but also set them to empty but this is great! If I was going to introduce another column with fields eg. attribute for each 'field' - is there way to add multiple fields to work with this or would i need to have separate script for each column (not the end of the world)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Actually, managed to do it for 2 columns by multiplying counter value 'counter.value * 2'. Thanks again!